# Space in IE7 due to h1 tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

In IE7, there is an extra spacing created between the question and the options, but only for the first question. If I remove the `<h1>` title, the gap disappears. It doesn't happen in IE8. What is the cause and how do I make it work in IE7?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .question { padding-bottom: 25px; } 
        .questionNumber { width:30px; float:left; } 
        .questionText { float:left; margin-bottom:5px; }
        .options { clear:both; margin-left:30px; } 
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Survey</h1> <!-- if this line is removed, the gap disappears -->
    <div class="question">
        <div class="questionNumber">1)</div>
        <div class="questionText">Question 1:</div>
        <div class="options">
            <input type="radio">Option 1 <br>
            <input type="radio">Option 2 <br>
            <input type="radio">Option 3 <br>
            <input type="radio">Option 4 <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question">
        <div class="questionNumber">2)</div>
        <div class="questionText">Question 2:</div>
        <div class="options">
            <input type="radio">Option 1 <br>
            <input type="radio">Option 2 <br>
            <input type="radio">Option 3 <br>
            <input type="radio">Option 4 <br>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s floating that causes the problem. Remove `float:left` from the declarations for `.questionText`.

Comment: I see, this is probably a more accurate answer. Should I just think of of it as IE7 bug, then? What if I want to use `float:right` there?

Answer (score 2):

put this style:

```
h1{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

**Note:** You are using html5 DOCTYPE. HTML5 was not supporting lower version ie.

Comment: The HTML5 doctype is irrelevant here.

Comment: Ok, it is the margin (specifically, the margin-bottom). Have to set margin to 0 and use padding for the spacing. This works for my case, but out of curiosity, what should I do if I cannot set the margin to 0 for any reason? Tried a bit with line-height as suggested on the other post, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your styles on the h1, it's probably line-height pushing it down.

```
h1 {
line-height:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

I'd suggest using a reset stylesheet as it will save you debugging headaches down the road

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

Reset your styles on h1. Just like this

```
h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

I think it might help you. Just try it.

Comment: When you say line-height: 0, am I supposed to really set it to 0, or can I set it some other value? Setting it to 0 really messed up the layout. Am I missing something?

Comment: just remove the line-height: 0 and check it.Other thing will be the same.